# Vue.js + Element UI + el-popover - dynamically changing trigger doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I want to change in runtime how my popover is opening (from 'hover' to 'click'). I added code similar to the below:

```
<el-popover 
    placement="top-start"
    width="200"
    :trigger="someCondition ? 'hover' : 'click'"
    :title="title"
    :content="content">
    <el-button slot="reference">Button</el-button>
 </el-popover>
```

The title and content successfully changes dynamically in runtime but the trigger stays with the initial value even if the condition changes.

What am I doing wrong?

PS - I am pretty new with vue.js (but very experienced with programming and other web frameworks - e.g. React).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `key` modifier on the `el-popover` as the element should be recreated

> The key special attribute is primarily used as a hint for Vue’s
> virtual DOM algorithm to identify VNodes when diffing the new list of
> nodes against the old list. Without keys, Vue uses an algorithm that
> minimizes element movement and tries to patch/reuse elements of the
> same type in-place as much as possible.

HTML:

```
 <el-popover
    :key="trigger"
    placement="top-start"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    :trigger="trigger"
    content="this is content, this is content, this is content">
    <el-button slot="reference">Hover to activate</el-button>
  </el-popover>
  <el-button @click="changebehavior">Change behavior</el-button>
```

JS:

```
data() {
  return {
    visible: false,
    trigger: 'hover'
  };
},
methods: {
  changebehavior() {
    this.trigger = 'hover' == this.trigger
      ? 'click'
      : 'hover'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `key` modifier

**Working example**

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        visible: false,
        title: 'Default title',
        content: 'Default content',
        trigger: 'click',
      };
    },
    methods: {
  changeToClick() {
  this.title= 'Click title';
   this.content= 'Click content will be here';
  this.trigger  = 'click';
  },
     changeToHover() {
  this.title= 'Hover title';
  this.content= 'Hover content will be here';
  this.trigger  = 'hover';
  },
}
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
  
  <el-popover 
   :key="trigger"
    placement="top-start"
    :trigger="trigger"
    width="200"
    :title="title"
    :content="content">
    <el-button slot="reference">Button</el-button>
 </el-popover>
 
 <el-button type="text" @click='changeToClick'>Change To Click</el-button>
  <el-button type="text" @click='changeToHover'>Change To hover</el-button>

</template>
</div>
```